# first time using jHipster, browser hangs after grunt serve

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster, yo

I'm very familiar with yo angular (fullstack) apps, and so I expected the yo jhipster app scaffolding to perform in a similar way.

So, I'm running a new project using jhipster. I've installed everything, built my app with maven, created an entity, and started up the app with `grunt serve`

it just hangs forever.

[image]

So, popping open the developer console, i'm seeing that there are no JS errors, and the initial page's GET request is just pending forever.

[image]

Three questions immediately come to mind:

1. what should I be seeing?
2. is there a reason why the url wont resolve to anything?
3. what do I do to load & view the app correctly?

Comment: Can you press F12 in Chrome and paste here the error that **Console** tool shows?

Comment: @JeanCedron there are no JS errors, because the main call to the app never stops pending, thus, nothing ever gets returned to the browser. see the updates.

Comment: Have you also started your server in a separate terminal? using `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to start up the server for backend (on a separate terminal window):

- If using Maven: `mvn spring-boot:run`
- If using Gradle: `gradle bootRun`

If you check the `Gruntfile.js` in the root folder:

```
browserSync: {
    dev: {
        bsFiles: {
            src : [
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    options: {
        watchTask: true,
        proxy: "localhost:8080"
    }
},
```

You find that the task `browserSync` is proxied to portal `8080`, which is the server started by `mvn spring-boot:run` or `gradle bootRun`

For your reference: http://jhipster.github.io/installation.html

Comment: it was failing to startup due to an error that I cannot understand. I'll create a separate SO question for that.